# How to pass values from iron-ajax to an element at the same level?

Tags: polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm trying to create a new element and I would like to bind data from outside the element, with iron-ajax. I've done something like

`<iron-ajax ... last-response="{{myval}}"></iron-ajax>
<my-elem values="{{myval}}"></my-elem>`

my problem is (and it's been several hours(days?) I'm trying to find the problem/solution) my element is getting `{{myval}}` (string, even if I set the property type to Object)
instead of the content of the json I get from iron-ajax, I'm pretty lost right now..
[the demo code is here](http://pastebin.com/YqqtE9qt), [the code of my element is here](http://pastebin.com/XNbCLiMJ) but I suspect my problem is really in the demo and not in the element.

I've seen this way of doing in [polycast 26](https://youtu.be/k1eR_3KqJms?list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN&t=358), but the difference is Rob is doing that inside an element, I do not since my element should get the data (the element is not in charge to download it).

Does someone has an advice about that ?

PS: I tried to have a different name than values, but it does not change anything, I also tried to change the function name from attached to something else,if this cause a problem, it's not about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data binding between elements only works within a Polymer element's local DOM or the special [`dom-bind` template element](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-bind) created for this purpose.

Your example code:

```
<demo-snippet>
    <template>
    <iron-ajax auto url="/demo/d1.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{myval}}"></iron-ajax>
    <d3spark-element yleg="Watt" ymax="2000" values="{{myval}}"></d3spark-element>
    </template>
</demo-snippet>
```

Should work as only:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <iron-ajax last-response="{{myval}}"...
  <d3spark-element values="[[myval]]"...
</template>
```

I don't think you can supply "content" nodes within `demo-snippet` and expect data binding to work between them.

Comment: That was it, thank you. The thing is, I did not expected to "magically" work, but, I had understood dom-bind was [only expected](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-bind)  when you are outside a polymer element. [demo-snippet](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-demo-helpers) **is** an element, so why should it be explicitly asked to do the bindings ?

Comment: In fact, it let the element works a bit too well, if I add the dom-bind, everything in the template is doubled...

Comment: Thanks to amurdock on slack, I found the solution, dom-bind should not be put on the template just after demo-snippet but on another template on his own.